# Customize Asp net Razor engine

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, typescript

I have an idea to extend standard razor engine and add a support of typescript processing. It will work very simple. We will just write typescript code in `<script language="typescript">` tag. Then razor crawl the page it standard process all `@` (C#) statements and then compile typescript in `<script language="typescript">` tags and replace it with output `javascript` code. So is it possible to extend razor engine this way? Where I can read about it? The second step is add typescript syntax support for VS editor. But it will be in future now I have an interest  for first question. Thanks.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea, still do you really believe that people using typescript would like to put all their code between script tags on the page? Would it also compile the referenced typescript code? Experience shows that compiling big typescript projects takes time. Compiling everything on the fly might impact the page load time.

Comment: As I know razor caches compiled pages. An it still possible to create a custom cache for compiled scripts.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to extend razor engine this way?  Where I can read about it?

Yes. But there aren't official docs for it, however it is open source : https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc

### Side note

Recommend you don't go down this path:

- too tightly linked to VS
- Not where the community is already at (use something like http://webpack.github.io/docs/)

Comment: Why is it that when a product is out of favor than using it causes a "tight link" i.e. "Don't use product x it causes a tight linkage.  Use product y instead."  Like product y itself does not introduce any less of a dependency.  So what if VS does in fact introduce a linkage or a dependency.  Whatever happened to evaluating products on a cost/benefit basis and using the ones with the most net benefit?  Razor is an awesome engine I would love to see it extended.

Comment: Agreed, but having more OSS support (and already documented workflow) is a definite thing to consider, that's all I am saying 